# Parse CSS using JSoup in Java

Tags: java, css, parsing

I am trying to parse https://www.avito.ru/voronezh. On page there are 50 elements:

```
<a class="item-description-title-link" href="/voronezh/mebel_i_interer/kuhni_1132166621" title="Кухни в Воронеже">
 Кухни
 </a>
```

But some of these elements has following CSS properties:

```
element.style {
}
7cad82b….css?b0b9a4e:1
.item_table.item-highlight .item-description-title-link {
    background-color: #fbfe23;
    line-height: 19px;
    color: #0091d9;
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 2px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How I can get only elements with `background-color: #fbfe23;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are trying to use Jsoup. Here is a solution using this lib. I  fetched all elements with class item-description-title-link in the page.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;


public class SouSoup {
    private static String url = "https://www.avito.ru/voronezh";

    /* Get Data */
    public static void getData() throws IOException, ParseException {
        System.out.println("Fetching file");
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements res=doc.getElementsByClass("item-description-title-link");
       for (Element elt : res) {
            System.out.println(res.text());
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException{
        SouSoup.getData();
    }
}
```